# Google Sheets: move a chart and still have it update from original data/arrays?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Can you move or copy a chart in Google Sheets into another EXISTING sheet and have it still update form the original data arrays?
I know you can move a chart into its *own sheet*, but I'm looking to move multiple charts onto one sheet so it's easy to view all in the same place.
Is it possible to do this and still have the chart update when data on the original sheet is updated?

Comment: Welcome. Please create a "learning lab" spreadsheet (a new spreadsheet to play and learn with), create a couple of charts then move them to another sheet and see what happens. If you need further help. edit your question and describe what happened.